# Scroll it on top and left, when the Pdf is zoom in my Cordova app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova, pdf

I'm developing a mobile app using Cordova and would like to know if there's a way zoom and scroll embedded pdf( HTML).

I put a file sample.pdf on my mobile app, and displayed using pdf.js. What I want scroll my sample.pdf on all side... top,left,right,bottom when zoom.

**I am able to scroll the pdf at right and bottom but unable to scroll it on top and left, when the Pdf is zoom**

I did check out https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/displaying-pdf-files-pdf.js-library, and for zooming in/out, I use hammer.js (http://hammerjs.github.io/)

I wanted it to scroll it on top and left, when the Pdf is zoom in my Cordova app

Attached is Screen..

[image]